# What encryption protocol is used by paragonie/Halite library by default?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, php, python

We're going to implement encryption between php server and python server. We decided to use paragonie/halite library (based on libsodium) on our php part. Python guy are asking what exact protocol from libsodium they should implement. And I don't know what to say them.

What encryption protocol is used by Halite library by default?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a protocol designed for transport encryption, like TLS, since you're talking about server to server communication?

Comment: This seems kinda off topic, as it is more of a question on libsodium. Have you checked their technical documentation? Maybe ask this on superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What encryption protocol is used by Halite library by default?

This is explained in the [Halite documentation](https://github.com/paragonie/halite/blob/master/doc/Primitives.md).

Halite uses XSalsa20 (the extended-nonce construction of the Salsa20 stream cipher) with a keyed BLAKE2b hash for the authenticator, Encrypt-then-MAC.

If you prefer to look at source code, [see here](https://github.com/paragonie/halite/blob/5f7b3e578e280540bfa9e9aa786eff2262807d92/src/Symmetric/Crypto.php#L191-L248).